# magento 1.9 get shopping cart price rule label

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, labels

I'm trying to display the label of the applied shopping cart price rule. I can display the rule name, but there is no label.

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId);
echo $rule->getName();  // <- this one displays the rule name
echo $rule->getLabel(); // <- this one displays nothing
var_dump($rule->getData()); // <- I don't see the label in the data
```

I have configured a label for each one of the storeviews.

¿How can I display the label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

```
var_dump($rule->getStoreLabel());
```

If you want all labels use following way:

```
$rule->getStoreLabels()
```

Comment: $rule->getStoreLabel() works fine, thank you